# SEARCH PEOPLE NEARBY

Tags: android, firebase

I am developing a Tinder-like app and I would need some advice on how to start searching for people nearby (obviously they have to be part of my database so be registered).
As a database I used Firebase. I have already created the Registration page, Login, Personal Settings, Insert photos, city and description, delete account etc ..
I would like to create on the Home page some cards of the people sought, simply filtered by Gender, Age and distance in Km. This is the Settings page:

SETTINGS XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/whiteshadowbackground">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/back_settings"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="636dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:text="BACK"
        app:backgroundTint="#7C0F0F"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/setDistance"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:max="1000"
        android:progress="100"
        android:scaleX="2"
        android:scaleY="2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.slider.RangeSlider
        android:id="@+id/agespinner"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:valueTo="90"
        android:valueFrom="18"
        app:values="@array/agechoice"
        android:stepSize="1"
        android:progress="18"
        android:min="18"
        android:max="90"
        android:scaleX="2"
        android:scaleY="2"
        app:tickVisible="false"
        app:trackColorActive="#9F1309"
        app:trackColorInactive="#9C9C9C"
        app:haloColor="#9C9C9C"
        app:thumbColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/agetext" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/SetDistanceFont"
        android:layout_width="198dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/aclonica"
        android:text="Maximum Distance"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/setDistance"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.013"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Distance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="245dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="245dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
        android:text="KM"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/setDistance"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/SetDistanceFont" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Gendertext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/aclonica"
        android:text="Gender"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.096"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/setDistance" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.779"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Gendertext"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/setDistance" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/agetext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/aclonica"
        android:text="Age"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.093"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Gendertext" />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

JAVA SETTINGS:

```
    package com.example.authenticatorapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.material.slider.RangeSlider;
import com.google.android.material.slider.RangeSlider.OnChangeListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class Settings extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    FirebaseAuth auth;
    Button back_settings;
    SeekBar setDistance;
    TextView Distance;
    Spinner spinner;
    RangeSlider agespinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        back_settings = findViewById(R.id.back_settings);
        setDistance = findViewById(R.id.setDistance);
        Distance = findViewById(R.id.Distance);
        spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        agespinner = findViewById(R.id.agespinner);

        //SETTARE LA DISTANZA
        setDistance.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                Distance.setText(String.valueOf(progress) + "KM");
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });

        //SETTARE L'ETA'
           // RangeSlider.OnChangeListener(new RangeSlider.OnChangeListener()){
                //slider.getValues() is returning an array of the (thumb-)values.


        //SETTARE IL SESSO
        //CREA L'ARRAY DEFINITO IN RESOURCES>VALUES>STRING E LO COLLEGA ALLO SPINNER
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.genderchoice, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        //CLICK SUL BOTTONE BACK PROFILO
        back_settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Profile.class));
            }
        });

    }

    //L'ADAPTER DELL'INTERFACCIA PER IL SESSO,PRENDE IL VALORE E LO METTE IN UNA STRINGA
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String sesso = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

Anyone have any ideas? I thank you in advance!! :)

Comment: You might want to edit your question to increase your chances of an answer. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **700 (seven hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: Done, I simplified the code by deleting the home page! Hope someone can help!

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries